# Turbolinks issues

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

In my ruby on rails program:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function () {  
  initFileCrop()  
  $(select2).select2({})
}
```

I discarded the big chunk of my code just to simplify my question.

When I click "go back" arrow and "go forward" to the original page, it will reload the initFileCrop(), which will cause an error saying that "Can't initialize croppie more than once". Also, the select box will double it number.

I sort of understand that issue. That is because every time I go back and go forward, it will trigger turbolinks:load.

How could I fix this issue? specifically not having the select box double its number and re-run the croppie function?

Comment: Were you able to fix your issue? This section of the turbolinks docs should be helpful: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#making-transformations-idempotent. You're on the right track with your thinking.

Comment: could you please add a chunk of code of your function initFileCrop()?